# Create Excel files with Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate, office-scripts, excel-365

I try to explain my problem.

I have an excel file (shared on Sharepoint) with a list of testing features.
I need to scrool this list and for each feature create an excel file from a template and rename it with the related feature name.

Is it possible to perform this task in Power Automate?
My idea is to create an Office Script to push features name in an array and the iterate it to create file?
Can you help me to solve this problem?

Thanks
Andrea

Comment: Do you want one Excel workbook for each feature? Or do you want one workbook where each worksheet represents a feature?

Comment: @BrianGonzalez I eant to create one Excek Workbook for each feature

Answer (score 0):

Here we go...

First of all, you'll need to set your trigger.

For the excel list (I guess it is a table, right?) you can use "List rows present in a table" for making a loop into the table's data:
[image]

Place (manually) the excell template into a Onedrive/Sharepoint folder and look for the "Get file content using path" action:
[image]

then you're going to use "Apply to each" for setting the actions you want to perform while running the list:
[image]

Now add "Create file" (Sharepoint) into "Apply to each", insert the path you wanna save each excel file generated by the flow and specify the file's name by typing the expression below (don't forget to replace "name_of_the_column" for the name of the column your features names are in):

```
items('Apply_to_each')["name_of_the_column"]
```

[image]

After specifying the file's name, insert the "File Content" you get from "Get file content using path" into File Content Field:
[image]

All done...
Time to run!